# D3.js x-axis time scale

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to do a scatter plot in D3.js with date on the x-axis. The code below is based on the scatter plot example on the d3 site. I must be doing something wrong in the attr('cx'
area...

```
var data =[

  {
    "title":"SUNY GENESEO COLLEGE STADIUM PHASE 2",
    "stage":"Biddate Set",
    "naples_update_date":"2/9/2014",
    "value":7500000,
    "value_type":"Confirmed",
    "ownership":"State",
    "work_type":"Alteration",
    "record_date":"1/21/2014",
    "floors":null,
    "floor_area":null,
    "floor_units":"",
    "land_area":null,
    "land_units":"",
    "structures":null,
    "units":0,
    "contract_type":"Open Bidding",
    "address":"1 College Cir",
    "city":"Geneseo",
    "state":"NY",
    "county":"Livingston",
    "date":1390911781
  },
  {
    "title":"KENTUCKY FAIR & EXPOSITION CENTER FREEDOM HALL-ROOFING",
    "stage":"Post Bid Results Pending",
    "naples_update_date":"2/10/2014",
    "value":2662903,
    "value_type":"Confirmed",
    "ownership":"State",
    "work_type":"Alteration",
    "record_date":"10/29/2013",
    "floors":2,
    "floor_area":null,
    "floor_units":"",
    "land_area":null,
    "land_units":"",
    "structures":1,
    "units":0,
    "contract_type":"Open Bidding",
    "address":"937 Phillips Ln",
    "city":"Louisville",
    "state":"KY",
    "county":"Jefferson",
    "date":1383132359
  }
];

var format = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y");
var dateMin = format.parse("20/03/2001");
var dateMax = format.parse("7/02/2001"); 

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var xValue = function(d) { 
  return format.parse(d.record_date);
  }, // data -> value
    xScale = d3.time.scale().domain([dateMin,dateMax]).range([0, width]), // value -> display
    xMap = function(d) { return xScale(xValue(d));}, // data -> display
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom");
var yValue = function(d) { return d.value;}, // data -> value
    yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]), // value -> display
    yMap = function(d) { return yScale(yValue(d));}, // data -> display
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");
// setup fill color
var cValue = function(d) { return d.ownership;},
    color = d3.scale.category10();
// add the graph canvas to the body of the webpage
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// add the tooltip area to the webpage
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

// don't want dots overlapping axis, so add in buffer to data domain
  xScale.domain([d3.min(data, xValue)-1, d3.max(data, xValue)+1]);
  yScale.domain([d3.min(data, yValue)-1, d3.max(data, yValue)+1]);

//x-axis
svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("x", width)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Date");

  // y-axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Value");

// draw dots
  svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 3.5)
  .attr("cx", xMap)
      .attr("cy", yMap)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(cValue(d));}) 
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(200)
               .style("opacity", 0.9);
          tooltip.html(d.title + "<br/> (" + xValue(d) + ", " + yValue(d) + ")")
               .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
               .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(500)
               .style("opacity", 0);
      })
  .attr('data-title',function(e){
return e.title;
})
.attr('data-value',function(e){
return e.value;
})
.attr('data-date',function(e){
return e.record_date;
})
.attr('data-sqft',function(e){
return e.floor_area;
});
```

I've searched around and tried to follow the tips out there, making sure the dates for the .range() are objects of the same format at the dates inside attr(cx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EC6TL/

The problem was in line:

```
xScale.domain([d3.min(data, xValue) - 1, d3.max(data, xValue) + 1]);
```

You cannot add and subtract `1` from dates. :-)

**Fix:**

```
xScale.domain([d3.min(data, xValue), d3.max(data, xValue)]);
```